# Default parameter in main method and pretty print a map in Scala

Tags: scala

This program print a table of factorial up to a given number. Given number 10, the output would be like this:

```
1 != 1
2 != 2
3 != 6
4 != 24
5 != 120
6 != 720
7 != 5040
8 != 40320
9 != 362880
10!= 3628800
```

Here is my attempt: (there's error in it)

```
package nick
import Factorial.factorial
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

object PPrintFactorial {
  def main(args: Array[String] = Array("12")) {
    //    if (args.length > 0)
    val listNum = 1 to args(1).toInt
    val listFac = listNum.map(factorial)
    val numFacPair = TreeMap((listNum zip listFac): _*)
    var padding: String = " "
    //    for (sp <- listNum)
    //      padding = " " * (10 - sp.toString.length)  
    for ((k, v) <- numFacPair) println(k + padding + " ! = " + v)
  }
}
```

Question:

1. Is the default parameter allowed in the main method? If yes, how to set it?
2. How to adjust padding when printing a map? As you can see in my commented part of the code, I failed add padding properly.

**Edit**

The problem with formatting:

There's one more space in front of `!` in `10!= 3628800` than others. If the input number is three digits, there would be two more spaces in front of the `100 !=`line. That is, the `!` is not vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1):

For the padding you could consider working with a tab instead of spaces to solve your problem in a very convenient way?

```
scala> println("1\t== x")
1    == x

scala> println("10\t== x")
10   == x

scala> println("100\t== x")
100  == x

scala> println("1000\t== x")
1000 == x
```

Comment: Ah, this is really easy yet an elegant way! Thank you! The only limitation is that in this way, the maximum digits of number is 7.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameters are allowed in the main method, but they won't be used. When you use `java ...` to run the main method of a class, Java *will* pass a parameter, which is an array with all the arguments.

If no argument is provided, Java still passes the parameter. The array will be empty, but it's still a parameter.

And even if that were not the case, Java has no knowledge of Scala defaults -- that's something that the Scala compiler inserts in the code, so it simply would not happen.

As to the formatting, you didn't explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. The problem with formatting: there's one more space in front of  `!` in `10!= 3628800` than others. If the input number is three digits, there would be two more spaces in front of the `100 !=` line. That is, the `!` is not vertically aligned.

Comment: But interesting idea to invoke defaults either in the Scala runner or ScalaClassLoader.run if args.isEmpty https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M1/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ObjectRunner.scala#L22 or https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M1/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/util/ScalaClassLoader.scala#L62

Comment: Field width formatting `m map { case (k,v) => f"$k%5d -> v" } foreach println` or build fmt string with `m.keys.max` and use `fmt format (k, v)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the default value of parameter, just check if the `args` array is empty. If it is empty, default it to your desired value. This should do:

```
val limitValue = (if (args.isEmpty) "12" else args(0)).toInt
val listNum = 1 to limitValue
```

For the padding, you might try something like this:

```
val maxLength = listNum.last.toString.length // assuming listNum has last() method

for ((k, v) <- numFacPair) {
  val padding = (k.toString.length - maxLength).abs
  println(k + (padding * " ") + " ! = " + v)
}
```

Note that padding is calculated each time. Your last element in `listNum` will be your maximum value (hence the longest) and the difference between length of `k` - the current element -  and `maxLength` will be the padding value. Then using string multiplication `padding * " "` you obtain that many spaces.

I hope I understood you correctly and I hope this works.

Comment: I got `PPrintFactorial.main(Array("10"))
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
  at PPrintFactorial$.main(<console>:11)
  ... 33 elided` But thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, snap! `args(0)`, not `args(1)`. That's the reason for exception most probably. I'll edit the answer when I have time. :)